# Shared class definitions for C#, TypeScript and Python

Tags: c#, python, typescript, azure-devops

We are developing a set of apps that share about 15 classes. The UI is Angular8, The API is C#, and we have some Azure Functions running Python. We're using Azure DevOps.

So far we've manually defined the classes in each separate project and manually checked that they are no mismatches. But as the number of apps grows, we're going to hit a wall soon.

Ideally we'd want to have the following scenario:

- define these classes in a C# class library and then generate their equivalent in TypeScript and Python (two other libraries)

  have these 3 class libraries available for import for the C#/TypeScript/Python apps

Is there a way to do this? Is it possible?
Are there alternatives?

There are ways to create a class library and share it through NuGet. 
https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/packagemanagement/

But we need the class definitions across TypeScript and Python too.

Comment: Assuming those classes only have properties, not methods, probably define the class in json and run a tool that generate the classes in 3 languages, json is good because it is like the common guy. Finding something that handles all type of combinations(c# to python, etc) is less probably. https://quicktype.io/

Comment: This may not work for your specific use case, but if you wanted to share the class library over Nuget you could just convert your Azure function into C# and share the model between them that way.  And then use JSON to convert between your UI and API.  If not, I agree with the comment above, use JSON for all translations.

Comment: @Bogdan Not get your response for several days, is Andro Font's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing these classes? Have you considered Protocol Buffers or Microsoft Bond? Could you use dynamic objects? How much of your complexity is wrapped up in ensuring static types? As suggested JSON can be used as neutral definition language and can then be translated into the programmer's secret weapon, a dictionary.